# How to pull json data using java

Tags: java, json

I am unable to pull data from this in java. The problem is that how **name_value_list** will be fetched afterwards. Thanks in advance.

```
{ 
  "id" : "ets7qkt1luugsj828jugs8vuq5",
  "module_name" : "Users",
  "name_value_list" : { "mobile_max_list_entries" : { "name" : "mobile_max_list_entries",
          "value" : null
        },
      "mobile_max_subpanel_entries" : { "name" : "mobile_max_subpanel_entries",
          "value" : null
        },
      "user_currency_id" : { "name" : "user_currency_id",
          "value" : "-99"
        },
      .
      .


      "user_language" : { "name" : "user_language",
          "value" : "en_us"
        },
      "user_name" : { "name" : "user_name",
          "value" : "abcd"
        },
      "user_number_seperator" : { "name" : "user_number_seperator",
          "value" : ","
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you got till now?

Comment: Post your parser code.

Comment: do you need only `name_value_list`?

Comment: yes i want get in name_value_list and get the JSONobject value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say to try using google's Gson() to deserialize.

First, build the entity (or object mapping) classes, something like:

```
public class MobileMaxListEntry implements Serializable {
@Expose
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@Expose
@SerializedName("name")
private String value;
//getters / setters
}
```

Do this for each entity you have. Then:

```
public class ValuesList implements Serializable {
@Expose
@SerializedName("mobile_max_list_entries")
private MobileMaxListEntry mobile_max_list_entries;
@Expose
@SerializedName("mobile_max_subpanel_entries")
private MobileMaxSubpanelEntry mobile_max_subpanel_entries;
//getters/setters for everything
}
```

Then, the response class:

```
public class MyResponseClass implements Serializable {  
@Expose
@SerializedName("id")
private String objectId;
@Expose
@SerializedName("module_name")
private String moduleName;
@Expose
@SerializedName("name_value_list")
private ValuesList valuesList;
//getters / setters for everything
}
```

Then, finally, in your code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = "your_json_here";
MyResponseClass  deserialized = gson.fromJson(json, MyResponseClass.class);
```

If you get an error, try adding default empty constructors for each class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply extract the data in `Map<String,Object>` from JSON string.

### [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
System.out.println(data.get("name_value_list"));
```

### [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {};
Map<String, Object> data = mapper.readValue(reader, typeRef);
System.out.println(data.get("name_value_list"));
```

---

You can create a **POJO** class that is exact replica of the JSON string and can convert it in the Java object using GSON.

sample code:

```
class MobileDetail{
    private NameValueList name_value_list;
    private String module_name;
    private String id;
}

class NameValueList{
    private NameValue mobile_max_list_entries;
    private NameValue mobile_max_subpanel_entries;
    private NameValue user_currency_id;
    private NameValue user_language;
    private NameValue user_name;
    private NameValue user_number_seperator;

}

class NameValue{
    private String name;
    private String value;
}

...

MobileDetail data =new Gson().fromJson(reader, MobileDetail.class);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data));
```